# Where can I see in depth about react-native link script?

Tags: react-native

Today, I've experienced that `react-native link` script isn't solid because about 10% of failure happened during linking which I had to `unlink` and `link` to make this actually working.

If I want to look in depth about this `linking` script, where could I see and test in actual react-native source code?

I've clone `react-native` repo and trying to find where it is.

Comment: Here are a few tips that I use before using `react-native link`. **1** Always make sure your code changes are committed to git before running the link command. **2** Always run the command as `react-native link package_name` **3** check the git diff, how does it compare to the manual linking instructions for the dependency **4** never link more than one package at once. These things stop me from having lots of errors when linking. Sometimes it is just easier to link manually that way you know that everything is in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I would search through the [PRs related to react-native link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr%20react-native-link), which should give you a pretty good idea which files are invlolved. You didn't mention whether you're having trouble with Android, iOS, or both, but [here's a PR related to linking android](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/21133/files) that I found, which call out these files...

- [local-cli/link/android/patches/makePackagePatch.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/21133/files#diff-d793d0c9de5c4f5773e5407a9bba811f)
- [local-cli/link/android/patches/revokePatch.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/21133/files#diff-d793d0c9de5c4f5773e5407a9bba811f)

So, it seems it's part of the `cli/link`

## Update

I dug a little deeper and it looks like this is actually where the linking is done for both Android and iOS
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Linking/Linking.js

Comment: Thanks. Could you also provide linking for ios? I'm having trouble on both.

Comment: Also, the link you provided doesn't exists in recent `react-native` version. They are all removed and replaced to `react-native-local-cli` which I can't look into.

Comment: @BooKoo Updated the answer with a link to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Linking/Linking.js